How to redirect api from one server to another server with proxy server inbetween the servers using nginx
I have a redhat server given by vendor lets say Server A , from this server nothing is accessible unless we raise a request to vendor and their network team have to whitelist whatever url we have to use
And We have our own server lets say Server B, this is a ubuntu server where some of the services are hosted. These services can be consumed by vendor in Server A using apis.
Our api looks like https://example.com/api/endpoint1 (url1), https://example.com/api/endpoint2 (url2), https://example.com/api/endpoint3 (url3). Vendor won't whitelist just the domain https://example.com. Only specific api urls are whitelisted
Now vendor whitelisted all three urls (url1, url2, url3) and i can make curl request to those urls from Server A
curl -v -X POST https://example.com/api/endpoint1 -H "Host: example.in" -k 
curl request comes to the Server B and working fine
Note: All requests to (url1, url2, url3) in Server B from Server A goes via proxy server which is http://<proxyIp>:<proxyPort>
My nginx configuration in Server A is like below
server {
         listen 8080 ssl;
         listen [::]:8080 ssl;

         server_name <Server A IP>;

         include /path/ssl.conf;

         // Other location blocks

         location /api/endpoint1 {
              proxy_pass https://example.com/api/endpoint1;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         }
}


When i do nginx -t i'm getting error like below
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "example.com" in /file/path
nginx: configuration file /file/path/nginx.conf test failed

I want to send api request from Server A to Server B via api with proxy server http://<proxyIp>:<proxyPort> inbetween the servers using nginx

"host not found" looks like a DNS problem.

what has to be done to solve the issue?

I have tried mentioning <SERVER_B_IP> example.in in etc/hosts files and set Host as example.in in nginx config but getting error like upstream timed out(110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: <CLIENT_MACHINE_IP>, server: <SERVER_A_IP>, request: "POST api/endpoint1 HTTP/1.1", upstream "https://<SERVER_B_IP>:443/api/endpoint1", host: "<SERVER_A_IP>:8000", referrer: "https://<SERVER_A_IP>:8080"
SERVER_B_IP and port is not whitelisted, only urls are whitelisted in SERVER_A
